# Update a field within a NamedTuple (from typing)

Tags: namedtuple

I'm looking for a more pythonic way to update a field within a NamedTuple (from typing).
I get field name and value during runtime from a textfile und therefore used exec, but I believe, there must be a better way:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.6
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from typing import NamedTuple

class Template (NamedTuple):
    number : int = 0
    name : str = "^NAME^"

oneInstance = Template()
print(oneInstance)
# If I know the variable name during development, I can do this:
oneInstance = oneInstance._replace(number = 77)
# I get this from a file during runtime:
para = {'name' : 'Jones'}
mykey = 'name'
# Therefore, I used exec:
ExpToEval = "oneInstance = oneInstance._replace(" + mykey + " = para[mykey])"
exec(ExpToEval) # How can I do this in a more pythonic (and secure) way?
print(oneInstance)
```

I guess, from 3.7 on, I could solve this issue with dataclasses, but I need it for 3.6

Comment: You can not update a namedtuple. It is immutable. Have a look at dataclasses.

Comment: Formally, you are right and I used the wrong wording. Practically, `oneInstance = oneInstance._replace(number = 77)` works for me like an update, and for `ExpToEval = "oneInstance = oneInstance._replace(" + mykey + " = para[mykey])"
exec(ExpToEval)` 
I'm looking for a better solution.

Comment: I've rephrased my question using dataclasses, question title is "Update a field in a dataclass with a field name known only during runtime"

Answer (score 0):

Using `_replace` on namedtuples can not be made "pythonic" whatsoever. Namedtuples are meant to be immutable. If you use a namedtuple other developers will expect that you do not intent to alter your data.

A pythonic approach is indeed the [dataclass](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html). You can use dataclasses in **Python3.6** as well. Just use the [dataclasses backport from PyPi](https://pypi.org/project/dataclasses/).

Then the whole thing gets really readable and you can use `getattr`and `setattr` to address properties by name easily:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Template:
    number: int = 0
    name: str = "^Name^"

t = Template()

# use setattr and getattr to access a property by a runtime-defined name  
setattr(t, "name", "foo")
print(getattr(t, "name"))
```

This will result in

```
foo
```